# Mapping hash dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, hash

I have an ActiveRecord hash like this

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Tipax::Devices::MobileDevice id: 1, serial_number: "234523", imei: "22", user_id: nil>]>
```

How can I map this hash to an array dynamically by its columns name(serial_number, imei)

my current code for mapping is the following:

```
mobile_devices.map do |mobile_device|
  [
    mobile_device.serial_number,
    mobile_device.imei,
  ]
end
```

but I want to have a method to send an array of columns (%w[serial_number imei])
and an ActiveRecord hash to generate this array from hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't `mobile_devices.pluck(:serial_number, :imei)` do what you need?

Comment: Thanks. but I want to add to array link_to method that use from id value: `link_to("<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>".html_safe, "/mobile_devices/#{mobile_device.id}/edit",
                                  remote: true, title: I18n.t(:'titles.edit'))`

Comment: @AbolfazlMahmoudi now this is something completely different than what you asked in your question. Are you trying to get a list of devices list in an index view?